# Connected to wifi but unable to access internet

Tags: internet

I've had no issues with wifi connection until randomly last night. I am connected to my personal wifi at home (which is confirmed working by all other devices). I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I've tried `ping 8.8.8.8` and get response from that.
I've also tried checking `$ sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved`, and it is confirmed active (running).
I'm relatively new to ubuntu so unsure where to go from here. Any help appreciated, happy to provide any new information.

Final Edit: Despite warnings from other commenters I hardcoded the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 in `/etc/resolv.conf` and then running `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` and this worked. I then reset my laptop to see if the fix remained on rebooting and it all seems to be working now.

Second Final Edit: I've now reconnected to my VPN and disconnected and all seems to be functional. The output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` is the following:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub.resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all 
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a 
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
# 
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search cable.virginm.net4
```

Edit 1: I've left all DNS as default. `$ ping -c google.com` gives no response.

Edit 2:
The DNS for my router are 194.168.4.100 and 194.168.8.100. When I check `$ resolvectl status` the output for Link 3 (wlo1) is the following:

```
    Current Scopes: DNS
    Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    Current DNS Server: 194.168.4.100
    DNS Servers: 194.168.4.100 194.168.8.100
    DNS Domain: cable.virginm.net
```

Edit 3: I occasionally use a VPN for work but have gone through the solutions on this post: [No Internet connection after disconnecting from VPN in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088950/no-internet-connection-after-disconnecting-from-vpn-in-ubuntu-18-04)
And none have corrected my issue.

Comment: I've added that all DNS is default. ping -c4 google.com gives no response.

Comment: No such luck with that. I've also tried pinging the DNS for the router and that responds, but not the IP.

Comment: Just tried, still no response.

Comment: I'm not currently using a vpn but I do occasionally to connect to work servers.

Comment: Link 3 (wlo1) has the current DNS Server set to the same DNS as my router and the correct DNS Domain.

Comment: I've tried to solutions on the question and answers for DNS problems after disconnecting from the VPN but none has solved my issue. Have added this and the output from ```resolvectl status``` to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just added all the final information form cat /etc/resolv.conf. Seems to all be cooperating now.

Comment: note that, some VPNs block output port 53 to prevent dns leak. opendns has tcp port 5353 enabled, maybe try `dig google.com @208.67.222.222 -p 5353` and without `-p 5353` to further troubleshoot